# Problem removing lines from TXT-file with strchr()

Tags: c

I have a file with a header (first 12 lines) that ends with '\r\n' which I want to remove from the file. The program below received one warning on compiling, "multi-character character constant", and crashes when executed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {

    FILE *file;
    char buffer[255];
    char *out;
    int ch = '\r\n';   <--- multi-character character constant here

    file = fopen("test.txt", "r+");

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL)
    {
        out = strchr(buffer, ch);
        printf("%s", out+1);
    }

    fclose(file);
    return(0);

}
```

Any ideas how this can be solved?

Comment: `strchr` searches the string for __one__ character.

Comment: That explains a lot... Any ideas how I can search for a string instead?

Comment: You can use `char crlf = "\r\n";` and `out=strstr(buffer,crlf);`

Comment: What is the purpose of `out = strchr(buffer, ch);
        printf("%s", out+1);` please?

Comment: Do you want to remove the whole lines or just the new-line (sequence)?

Comment: The purpose of the code was to find the characters "\r\n" and delete them including everything before them.

Comment: How about a tiny state machine?

Comment: The problem is with the variables (therefore the warning). However, I have no idea where or why...

Comment: "*and delete them including everything before them*" so you'd ended up with just `"\r\n"`, as by definition of `fgets()` there will never be anything after the `'\n'`.